# Location based application for smartphones with no GPS chip

Tags: blackberry, gps

Is it possible to develop location (longitude, latitude) based application for Blackberry smartphones with no internal GPS chip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Devices can determine their position based on known locations of cell towers and/or WiFi hotspots that are in range. It's usually not as precise as GPS, but it can still be serviceable.

Skyhook Wireless is one of the major providers:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyhook_Wireless

http://www.skyhookwireless.com/

Comment: The official SDK doesn't support Blackberry (see http://www.skyhookwireless.com/developers/sdk.php), how do you make it work?
On the other hand, Google also has a Wi-Fi positioning service (see http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/GeolocationAPI) ; to use it you would have to collect the surrounding Wi-Fi BSSIDs (MAC addresses) and send then in a request to their server.
Anyway, the best way would be to use the ad-hoc Blackberry location API if there is any... But I don't know this platform.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can get location information.

There are three different modes that you can use to get location.

-> cell site: Use this mode to obtain location information from cell site towers.

-> assisted: Use this mode to get location information from satellites using a PDE. 

-> autonomous: Use this mode to get location information from the GPS receiver on the BlackBerry device without assistance from the wireless network.

You can use cell site or assisted mode to get location.

You can find more information at http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/644/GPS_and_BlackBerry_Maps_Development_Guide.pdf

Jim.

Comment: Hi jim..I have heard that the only mode available for GSM devices is autonomous mode. Is it true??